# Warnings repeated in storyboard after every restart of Xcode 8 for only one ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I have more than twenty viewControllers. I recently updated to Xcode 8. All are fine except one. I solved but it always shows same warnings after every restart of Xcode.

see below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am struggling with these issues since June, when Xcode 8 was released in its second Beta. Once I update many frames to suggested constraints, issues come back again after restarting IDE.

Rather than reconstruction of my full storyboard (as this can be caused by setting constraints in older way), I always update frames.

Now in **Xcode 8.1 updated version**, there is a **shortcut** button for this.

Just select the problematic view's superview (containing mentioned constraints), and click this **update frames** button:

[image]